# VB.NET Value of Type "class" be converted to "type"

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an interface like so:

```
Public Interface IDescriptionIdentityPair
    Property Id() As String
    Property Description() As String
End Interface
```

I have a class like so:

```
Public Class DescriptionIdentityPair : Implements IDescriptionIdentityPair

    Public Property Id As String Implements IDescriptionIdentityPair.Id
    Public Property Description As String Implements IDescriptionIdentityPair.Description

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Description
    End Function
End Class
```

I have a method like so:

```
Public Shared Function AddEmptyRow(Of T As IDescriptionIdentityPair)(ByVal collection As IList(Of T)) As IList(Of T)
    Dim AddEmptyRowToCollection = collection
    collection.Insert(0, New DescriptionIdentityPair With {.Id = "", .Description = FxApplication.DefaultText})
    Return collection
End Function
```

I am getting a compile time error when trying to insert the new instance of the DescriptionIdentityPair class, that the value of type "DescriptionIdentityPair" cannot be converted to T. I even tried casting the DescriptionIdentityPair to it's interface (in desperation), but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Why return the list at all?  Any code that is calling the `AddEmptyRow` method clearly already has a reference to the list.

Comment: @StevenDoggart To make method chaining possible?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yes, I figured that would be the only valid reason.  I was just suspecting that it may not be for any good reason at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is correct. Consider a situation when you have another class implementing your interface:

```
Public Class AnotherDescriptionIdentityPair : Implements IDescriptionIdentityPair
```

And you call your generic method with `T = AnotherDescriptionIdentityPair`:

```
Dim list As New List(Of AnotherDescriptionIdentityPair)
AddEmptyRow(list)
```

What would happen when you tried adding instance of `DescriptionIdentityPair` to `List(Of AnotherDescriptionIdentityPair)`?

You can fix that addint `New` generic constraint to your method and initializing `New T` instead of `New DescriptionIdentityPair`:

```
Public Shared Function AddEmptyRow(Of T As {New, IDescriptionIdentityPair})(ByVal collection As IList(Of T)) As IList(Of T)
    Dim AddEmptyRowToCollection = collection
    collection.Insert(0, New T With {.Id = "", .Description = "DefaultDescription"})
    Return collection
End Function
```

Comment: +1 for the information. But you solved my main problem in a comment below; I didn't know that IList wasn't covariant (unless it has a get indexer)!

I can remove the generic constraint and now just use IEnumerable(Of IDescriptionIdentityPair) as the argument type

Comment: @contactmatt But you won't be able to add items to `IEnumerable`, because it's read-only collection interface! You could only return new `IEnumerable` with new element and all source elements, e.g. using `Concat` extension method.

Comment: it seems to be working by converting the IEnumerable parameter to a list, then inserting an item into it.

Comment: Yes, that should work as long as you don't provide `List` of different class implementing your interface. Otherwise you'll get runtime conversion exception. I would advice not to go this way. Why don't you follow my answer and add `New` generic constraint?

Comment: @contactmatt You can't use this trick due to same issue - the `List` is not covariant.